# Deleting log files which are a week old

Tags: batch-file

I need some help in writing a script which deletes all "log" files which are 7 days old. As I am going for a holiday, this process is done manually every week by me. Hence I was thinking to create a batch file and put that in the task scheduler to run every week.

eg: There is folder called "cache" and then there are 100 folders starting test-01,test-03,test-05

then inside these test folders there are logs files which are dated like 120614.log,130614.log etc.. The script should identify these log files under every folder and then delete if they are 7 days old.

Comment: take a look at `forfiles /?`

Comment: Are the last modified dates reliable in determining the 7 days and older?  Are there any other `.log` files within the folder tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) in a somewhat peculiar way.

First use robocopy to MOVE the week-old log files from your log folder tree to a temporary folder and after that remove the temporary folder. As a bonus you could 7zip the moved log files before you remove them.

```
robocopy c:\cache %TEMP%\ERASECACHE /MOV /MINAGE:7 
rmdir /S /Q %TEMP%\ERASECACHE
```

#### How does this work

From robocopy /? we learn:

> Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]
>
> /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
>   /MINAGE:n :: MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.

And from rmdir /?

> RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> - /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory tree.
> - /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S

%TEMP% is a well-known environment variable that holds a directory where the current user has write permission