# Delete files in subdirectories via SFTP without SSH which are older than a week

Tags: bash, sftp, lftp

**Context**

Currently I am pushing data to a *SFTP-server* which other processes and systems than use for further stuff. All files share a root folder, but they're subdivided into subfolders according to certain categories. This folder structure must not be changed and cannot be altered. After a certain time period (currently 7 days) I need to automatically delete those files.

Unfortunately, the server has strict access rights and I can only access a specific directory via *SFTP*; *SSH* etc. is forbidden. The challenge in such an automated process lies within these restrictions:

- Only *SFTP*-protocoll
- No change in any folder-logic allowed; old and new files need to share the same directories
- The *SFTP*-command has to be issued from a *CRON*-job. Thus, the *SFTP*-commands need to be handled as one-liners.
- Nothing can be installed/changed on the SFTP-server

So far I know that I can delete files in one-liners this way:

```bash
echo "rm $_file_name" | sftp $username@$sftp_server
```

However, the problem I struggle the most with is reading in the files on the SFTP-server in one line and filter this output by the date-criterion.

**Question**

*How can I achieve a CRON-job deleting files only via SFTP in a directory given they are older than a week?*

---

Note: I am aware of questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289648/deleting-log-files-which-are-a-week-old) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461944/delete-files-older-than-7-days-from-a-remote-sftp-with-pentaho); anyhow, these do not share the limitations I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I figured out a solution in a stepwise-learning Process:

**Step 1: Retrieving all subdirectories**

First I needed to get all directories the files are stored in.
Given the assumption that all relevant directories are subdirectories of `\IN`, my solution was to get the `String`-return for that information and iterate over the splitted `String.

```sh
# Get the string the sftp-command returns for listing all directories in /IN.
sftp_dirs=$(echo $(echo ls | sftp $username@$sftp_server:/IN))

# Then erase the log-information from that string sftp appends to it.
# This leaves a string which can be split in order to iterate over it.
process_dirs="${sftp_dirs/'Changing to: /IN sftp> ls '/}"

# Now iterate over each directory and retrieve the files.
for _dir in $(echo $process_dirs | tr " " "\n")
do
     # Fill in Step2
done
```

**Step 2: Retrieving all files and their creation dates**

The files creation timestamps on the SFTP-server are the dates I pushed the files to the server. Thus, getting files stored on the server for more than 7 days can be identified by their creation time.

The challenge here is to retrieve this information from the echo-output of SFTP since. Since I have all necessary rights to install whatever I need on the server running the CRON-job, I used the help of `LFTP` for this since I couldn't do it with pure SFTP.

Finally, the solution is to read an array from LFTPs output.

```sh
# Returns an array with all files stored in $_dir with their respective timestamps.
# $_dir is the loop-variable from Step 1
readarray -t _files <<< "$(lftp -u $username, sftp://$sftp_server:/IN/$_dir -e "cls -B --date --time-style long-iso; exit")"
```

Note that I configured the timestamp to `long-iso` for further processing.

Thus, now iterate over all files in order to identify the ones older than 7 days like:

```sh
for _file in "${_files[@]}"
do
    # Fill in Step3
done
```

**Step 3: Retrieve and delete old files**

Here straight forward the code:

```sh
# Get the files date in the desired date format
# (remember that long-iso was chosen in Step 2)
# _file is the loop-variable from Step 2
_file_date=$(date -d "${_file:0:10}" +%s)
_file_name="/IN/"$_dir"/"${_file:17}

# Compare the date-difference
deletion_date=$(date -d 'now - 7 days' +%s)
_datediff=$(( (_file_date - deletion_date) / 86400 ))
```

Finally, if the datediffs results shows that the file is older than 7 days, delete it

```sh
if [ $_datediff -lt 0 ]
then
    # Pass the file to sftp and issue the delete command.
    echo "rm $_file_name" | sftp $username@$sftp_server
fi
```